# self.navigationItem available in any class?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

If a viewController is in a navigationStack(probably top of stack),
does it automatically possess self.navigationItem?

I keep seeing self.navigationItem and self.navigationController without much context in questions and tutorials, and wonder where that variables are set.

- edit

Wow thanks for the fast answers.
Where would I have spotted the info(about self.navigationItem) in the official doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if its in a stack it does have a `self.navigationItem`, if its not in a navigation stack `self.navigationItem` would equal to nil

This property is defined in an objective c class extension

```
@interface UIViewController (UINavigationControllerItem)
```

it defines the properties of `UIViewController` related to the `navigation controller`

Comment: Thanks, where in the doc says so? Is this a relatively new addition to the iOS library?(5.0+?)

Comment: No actually its not a new addition, its prior to 4 i guess am not sure its defined in UINavigationController.h

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will see the `self.navigationItem` and `self.navigationController` properties set in every controller that is added to the stack of navigation controller. These properties get set once you call `pushViewController:animated` or `initWithRootViewController:`.

Answer (score 0):

They are not set by you, unless you specifically tell it. There are others properties that are not assigned by you directly as well, for example:

```
self.tabBarController;

self.parentViewController;
```

That's why you should check if it is `nil`, before trying to access a property.